# Copy Webpack Plugin pattern for maintaining folder structure

Tags: webpack

I am using thge copy-webpack-plugin for webapck to copy files from my src folder to the dist folder.  I want the process to maintain the folder structure when doing so.

My folder structure is as follows:

|- src
|-components
|- my-component
|-view.html

I would like the plugin to copy only html files in the component folder to the dist folder maintaining the folder structure above.

I have accomplished the following so far:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "./src/components/*/*.html", to: "[name].html" },
            ],
        }),
    ],
};
```

The above simply copies the html files to the dist folder, the original folder structure is lost.

I would need to get the folder name where the html resides in and use that in the "to" patrtern.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Please see this example from the [CopyWebpackPlugin Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/).

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: "**/*",
          to: "[path][name].[ext]",
          context: "src/"
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

`src/` is the relative path here. To use an absolute path start with a slash (`/src/`).

UPDATE: I changed the code example to fit your circumstances.

Comment: I originally tried this, but it also copies the src folder to the dist folder, I only wish for it to copy the contents of the src folder.. The result should be: - dist -components - my-component -view.html

Comment: I think you can add your desired root as `context` beside the `path` and the `to` specifications.

Comment: Like this `context: 'src/'`. I'll update my answer too fit your circumstances.